# Getting list row id in list view

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

If I have a listview being populated with webservices and the elements added in each row have a unique id stored in the array list which utilizes a hashmap to store data,thn what would be the simplest way to obtain the id of the data,that was clicked in the row..
I am using a base adapter on my list,

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Third parameter is Position of Item in the list.

Comment: well I know how to get the position ,but I don't knw how to compare tht with the position in the array list tht I'm using

Comment: What you want to do? You want to compare value of Arraylist with value of ListView at particular position???

Comment: Yes for example if it has a unique json id assigned to it,I wish it to retrieve that from the arraylist when I click on the list item

Comment: So retrieve Item position and get the JSON Id from the arraylist using arraylistobject.get(position).

Comment: well I use mylist.get(position); to get the position ,now its showing the int value of the position ,nw if xyz is at that position how do i show that in a toast?? coz putting position in toast only shows the int value

Comment: String.valueof() is the inbuilt function you are looking for and if you find solution helpful don't forgot to upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

set on item click listener on listview. it will return position of the clicked item in the adapter (equivalent to position in the array list). you can fetch the id using that.

Comment: yes I know that much ,but I am new to coding so I dont knw hw to fetch the data of that postion from the array list

Comment: arraylist.get(index);
index is the 'position' that you are getting on on click
arraylist is the ArrayList with which you are populating the list

Comment: `lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),lv.getAdapter.getItem(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });`

Comment: okay, this gave me the position from the arraylist ,now if for example the position has "xyz" as its title/element ,how do I show that in the toast??

Comment: you are also getting a View (say v) along with the position. use
`TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.id_of_textview_in_your_layout);
tv.getText(); //this will get you the title`

Answer (score 1):

use this method listView.getItemAtPosition(position). It got a position you can use

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Get item at position like this:
        // listView.getItemAtPosition(position));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use the `adapter.getItem(position)` function you'll be able to get the item stored in the ListView in that specific position.

***update:*** this is of-course in the `setOnItemClickListener`

Comment: well I know how to get the position ,but I don't knw how to compare tht with the position in the array list tht I'm using

Comment: @AalokSharma, the `getItem` will get you the item in the list in the specific position. try looking at Krishnakant Dalal's answer